# If $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{3n-1}{3n}$ and $a_0=1$, find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

## Problem

Assume that $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\dfrac{3n-1}{3n}(n=1,2,\cdots)$ and $a_0=1$. Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n$.

## Attempt

Since
\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{a_n}{a_0}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{3k-1}{3k}=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{3k}\right)=\exp\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{3k}\right)\right],
\end{align*}
hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\exp\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{3k}\right)\right].
$$
But $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3k}\right)$ is divergent. I'm confused with this result.

Comment: At a glance, the sum diverges to negative infinity (each summand is negative), so the product diverges to zero. What are you confused by?

Comment: Oh。。。。。I think too much！

Answer (score 1):

So, you already know that $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1-\frac1{3k}\right)$ is arbitrarily negatively large for large $n$ (at least I hope that is what you meant when you say $S_n$ diverges), i.e., $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=-\infty.$$  What should the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{S_n}$ be if $S_n\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?  Maybe, something like squeeze theorem:
$$0<e^{S_n}\leq \frac{1}{1-S_n}\,,$$
since $e^{x}\geq 1+x$ for all $x\geq 0$, and plug in $x=-S_n$.